# Issue with webhook on github

Tags: php, github, webhooks

I am new to this, but I am getting a 502 response for my webhook on github. It done locally. I put in the localhost/deploy.php, and I've tried localhost.com/deploy.php, I've tried using ngrok. Like I said, I've never done this before so< i'm not sure what is wrong.

Below is my deploy.php

```
<?php
use CompleteSolar\Home\Controllers\DeployController;
require_once __DIR__.'/setup.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$controller = new DeployController();
exit(
    $controller->deploy(
        $config->getProperty(["github","localRoot"]),
        $config->getProperty(["github","branch"]),
        $config->getProperty(["github","repoSecret"]),
        $config->getProperty(["github","deployCommands"]),
        $config->getProperty(["bugsnag","clientId"])
    )
);
```

Setup.php

```
    <?php use CompleteSolar\HelioConfig\Utilities\Config;
use CompleteSolar\HelioTrack\Handlers\BugsnagHandler;
    use CompleteSolar\HelioTrack\Handlers\ErrorHandler;
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
    $configPath = __DIR__.'/../config/default.ini';
    $config = new Config($configPath,true);
    $errorLevel = $config->getProperty(["general","errorLevel"]);
    error_reporting($errorLevel);
    ini_set('display_errors', $errorLevel ? 'On' : 'Off');
    //       Configure Bugsnag
    if(!isset($bugsnag)){
        $bugsnag = new BugsnagHandler(
            $config->getProperty(["bugsnag","clientId"]),
            $config->getProperty(['github','branch']),
            E_ERROR
        );
        $errorHandler = new ErrorHandler($bugsnag);
        set_error_handler(array($errorHandler, "handleError"));
        set_exception_handler(array($errorHandler, "handleException"));
    }
    ?>
```

DeployController.php

```
<?php
namespace CompleteSolar\Home\Controllers;
use alanmanderson\clever_deploy\CleverDeploy;

class DeployController {

    public function deploy($localRoot, $branch, $repoSecret, $cmds, $bugsnagApiKey){
        $cd = new CleverDeploy($localRoot, '', '', $branch, $repoSecret);
        $cmds[] = "curl -d \"apiKey=$bugsnagApiKey&releaseStage=$branch\" http://notify.bugsnag.com/deploy";
        return $cd->deploy($cmds);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: localhost is only for four local enviroment avaible. Maybe you can public your local server but I would not recommend it. Try it with an remote host.

Comment: I made progress. I forgot to change my apache config file when I changed around my directories. Just need to figure out some issues with the php. I have a couple of warnings and a fatal error.

Comment: Warning: parse_ini_file(C:\complete-solar\dev\CompleteSolar.com\public/../config/default.ini): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\complete-solar\dev\CompleteSolar.com\vendor\completesolar\helioconfig\src\Utilities\Config.php on line 8

Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in C:\complete-solar\dev\CompleteSolar.com\vendor\completesolar\helioconfig\src\Utilities\Config.php on line 19

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'OutOfBoundsException' with message 'general not found in config file.' in C:\complete-solar\dev\CompleteSolar.com\vendor\completesolar\helioconfig\src\Utilities\Config.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\complete-solar\dev\CompleteSolar.com\public\setup.php(9): CompleteSolar\HelioConfig\Utilities\Config->getProperty(Array) #1 C:\complete-solar\dev\CompleteSolar.com\public\deploy.php(3): require_once('C:\complete-sol...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\complete-solar\dev\CompleteSolar.com\vendor\completesolar\helioconfig\src\Utilities\Config.php on line 20